# File system is 100% full

Tags: disk-usage

Recently, my system disk, somehow, got filled up to 92%.

According to the recommendations in the forums, I removed (using the Synaptics) obsolete version of Linux kernels (which lead to ONLY 62% of the system filled), cleaned the system trash etc., even tried to removed emails from Evolution...

The computer has been on since then (for an hour or two), and then I've got a message of the system FULL (100%)! Any suggestions?

Comment: I've just ran the Disk Usage Analyser, that's shown a HUGE file in the .cache directory. The file's come from a system utility, which sits in the System Tools->Administration->System Testing...
Shift-Deleted it and got ONLY 56% of the disk taken...
Thanks to everybody for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Something is rapidly filling your disk.

My first shot would be to check if there are some unusually big files in `/var/log` and subdirectories.

Useful commands:

```
du -sh *
```

will list all directory of file in current directory with the size;

```
ls -l --sort=size | head -10
```

will list the 10 biggest files of current directory. If you find which file is growing and with which data you are a step nearer to the solution...

Comment: yeah the logs occupies the whole disk; I delete them & the Ubuntu box can work right after; thank you.! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Did you check you log files? Sometimes applications running in debug mode can write huge log files that take up all space.

Do sudo du -sh * . on your root to find out the FS utilization directory wise and post it here if you can.

Another thing that happens sometimes when you have mounts on NFS is that some open files got deleted forcefully and the orphans start getting huge and huge till it takes up all space in no time.