# No space left on Filesystem after executing bleachbit

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

I had few disk space (but still i had some) and i decided to run bleachbit.

After restarting i can't login, i am in a loop in the login page of ubuntu.
I can login with alt+f2.

Then any command I run tells me i have no space left (which i don't understand because even before running bleachbit I still had some). So i guess bleachbit did corrupt some file or disk partition ?

Here is the stat of `dh -f` and `dh -i`

[image]

I am stuck now, what can I do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File system is 100% full](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405060/file-system-is-100-full)

Comment: This happens sometimes when you use the "permanently delete files" feature @user535733

Comment: Have you checked if there are any large files hanging around in /tmp or whereever bleachbit creates its temporary files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rebooting on recovery mode i could make some space and now I understand that my /root/cache is 77G but I don't get how/why.

Commands that helped me :

- Size of dirs `du -ahd1 | sort -hr | head -10`